# ImagePullBackOff Error

Tags: minikube

I'm using Minikube on Windows based machine. On the same machine, I also have docker-machine setup.

I've pointed docker client towards minikube’s docker environment. This way, can see  Docker environment inside Kubernetes.

Without issues, I can build docker images & run docker containers from Minikube VM. However, when I try to start any docker container via kubectl(from PowerShell), its failing to start primarily as if kubectl can't find docker image due to following error -

> Failed to pull image "image name": rpc error: code = Unknown desc =
>   Error response from daemon: repository "image-repo-name" not found:
>   does not exist or no pull access Error syncing pod

I don't know what's missing. If "docker run" can access the image why "kubectl" can not do?

Here my Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:4.4
EXPOSE 9002
COPY server.js .    
CMD node server.js
```

Comment: That "repository "image-repo-name" sounds suspicious. Can you share more, e.g. dockerfiles, exact kubectl commands that you use? It looks like your minikube VM does not see the image repository on your docker-machine setup.

Comment: updated original thread with Dockerfile. It seems, issue was docker image not having an explicit tag name as pointed out by David Dehghan

Comment: As a side note, get a slimmer image, like 4.x-alpine. Preferably go for node 8 right away, but regardless of which, a slim image reduces the end result size quite a lot.

Comment: Thanks, agree on going with lighter image. Alpine images do not come with by default bash installed. So it has to be included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your image path in your yaml is correct. That image should exist on your local machine. It should be named with a number not "latest"

Have this in your deployment yaml:

```
    image: redis:1.0.48
```

run "> docker images" to see the list of images on your machine.

Comment: Thanks David Dehghan, as you described, it was issue with docker image not having an explicit tag other than "latest". When I used a number like "v0", kubectl can grab the image and I don't see any - ImagePullBackOff Error. However, I do see - CrashLoopBackOff error.

Comment: Running "kubectl describe pods node-test-app-766b7bbd55-xlpn4" produces below output(added partial only) -
      State:       Waiting
      Reason:    CrashLoopBackOff
    Last State:  Terminated
      Reason:    ContainerCannotRun
      Message:   oci runtime error: container_linux.go:262: starting container process caused "exec: \"deployment\": executable file not found in $PATH"

      Exit Code:    127

Seems issue with "COPY" command in Dockerfile. Don't know exact answer though.

Comment: I found the issue, it was my mistake where I didn't add "deployment" executable in PATH environment variable.